# iOS Data - SQL v. JSON - which data storage architecture will be most performant

Tags: ios, database, json

I have an existing HTML5 web app which I am going to port to a native iOS app.  The current app uses MongoDB (i.e. JSON) to store all server-based data.  The MongoDB server will still supply central data services to the iOS app, but large quantities of data will also be held on the iOS client (e.g. 100,000 name and address records).

It seems my choices are to use SQLite or some sort of JSON framework.  The name and address records need to be locally searchable using a high-performance predictive search (i.e. display search results while user types).

Can anyone advise on which data architecture/strategy would be most functional/performant on the iPad?

btw - I am probably going to use MonoTouch to build the iOS app.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go SQlite, and investigate Apple's [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html) as an option as it's backed by sqlite and a very complete package for database storage within an iOS app.

If you want to interact with the sqlite database directly checkout [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) as a good objective c abstraction layer.

A comercial option could be a package I've seen called [Locayta Search Mobile](http://www.locayta.com/iOS-search-engine/locayta-search-mobile/) - they have some good demo code

Answer (score 0):

Without a doubt, use SQLite. Its performance will always beat simple JSON reading.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  Do you think that a predictive search with SQLite will perform ok with 100k contacts?  Or should I load the entire database into a collection which I can then enumerate/search from code?

Comment: @joyrneyman I've had 400-600k entries in an in app sqlite database and it's pretty good (not great, but pretty good). CoreData (as I mentioned) can handle the memory/disk paging for you too.

Comment: @Journeyman Unless you want to write massive algorithms that do the searching for you, I'd leave it up to SQLite to do that.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt This answer is quite old at this point, so I'm curious if you think it still applies.  If so, I'd like to know why you say this.  I'm skeptical that joining tables is faster than pulling JSON, especially if you can access a JSON doc directly by key.  Nothing against SQLite, it's just one of the reasons people use NoSQL DBs is for the performance because by nature relational systems have constraints that slow them down.

Comment: @Hod Nothing changed. JSON is still slow to parse and unless you intend to have all data in memory all the time, you're much better off using a storage method that involves searching on the disk instead of in memory.